# How can i get name of the picked image from photolibrary

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, filenames

In my app i have to use photos from  photolibrary ,i can get photo from library and can use that in my app but i'm unable to get the name of selected image

I'm using this

```
 //accessing photo library like this
-(IBAction)btnAttachFileClicked:(id)sender
{
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

        [picker release];


    }
}


//to get name of the selected image i'm using this

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
{


    NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    __block NSString *fileName = nil;

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
        fileName = [asset.defaultRepresentation filename];
    } failureBlock:nil];



}
```

but i cannot get image name when testing on simulator from this code,i imported AssetsLibrary framework ,is there any modifications to do please help me

i'm getting assetUrl as  "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=8542B1A1-7EAD-4CCB-A85B-8450826B49FA&ext=PNG"

Comment: I don't think you can get the name of the image. Through ALAsset you can only get the URL. What do you exactly mean with "name"?

Comment: @patapple now, i'm getting name as" IMG_0008.PNG ",next to filename i'm assigning it to NSString but it is becoming null  for later use